# Angular 9: how to disable ios mobile browser double tap zooming

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-cli-v9, ios-web-app

Angular 9: how to disabled ios mobile browser double tap zooming.

have tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, , initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">

touch-action: none;

-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `touch-action: manipulation` to the element you want to prevent zoom on double tap.

[From documentation;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#manipulation)

**manipulation: **
Enable panning and pinch zoom gestures, but disable additional non-standard gestures such as double-tap to zoom. Disabling double-tap to zoom removes the need for browsers to delay the generation of click events when the user taps the screen. This is an alias for "pan-x pan-y pinch-zoom" (which, for compatibility, is itself still valid).

Comment: Working for me.. on which element you are adding this tag?

Comment: add onClick={e => e.preventDefault()} on element.

Comment: angular not javascript.